# Android Marshmallow : VOIP application using PJSIP library sometimes takes long time to acquire wake lock during incoming call while device is idle

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, pjsip, android-wake-lock

I'm currently fixing issues of an existing VOIP application on Android which uses PJSIP library.

This application communicates with the PJSIP library using JNI and the PJSIP library sends callbacks through JNI as well (during incoming call etc.).

The application works fine in Lollipop.

One of the issues reported by the testing team was that while the application was running on a Marshmallow device (Android 6.0 / 6.0.1), sometimes the application failed to receive calls while device was idle.

Initially I checked the issue and found that the application was not sending SIP registration request periodically (which was the responsibility of the PJSIP library)and hence the application was loosing registration at the server after its registration lifetime was over.

Then I searched the Internet and came to know about the Doze mode in Android Marshmallow.

I read the following documentation regarding [Doze Mode](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) and changed the implementation a little.

The application's SIP registration lifetime was 20 minutes and we're using an alarm manager (using setAndAllowWhileIdle())to send a registration request in every 15 minutes (since in doze mode 15 minutes is the minimum time gap between two consecutive alarms).

Here also I experienced some issues in Marshmallow and found that the alarm manager was not been fired sometimes.
Then I changed the implementation for Marshmallow and used setAlarmClock method.

Everything was running fine since then till the testing team reported the issue of not receiving of incoming calls occasionally in Marshmallow.

I checked the log and found that occasionally the device takes long time to acquire the wake lock (around 20-30 seconds) and thus a timeout occurred while the incoming call arrived and the device was idle.

The application doesn't use GCM push and we've programmed it to ask the user to avoid battery optimizations for this application in Marshmallow.

Now my question is that how can I overcome this delay in acquiring the wake lock while the device was idle? Or in other words what should be the best practice (if any) to achieve the functionality of incoming call irrespective of the device mode and without using GCM?